# Deleting duplicates which are identified as equal up to rearrangement of sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of integer 2-tuples `s = { {{3,4},{11,5}} , {{11,5},{3,4}}, {{5,5},{3,2}} }` (in reality this set is much larger).

I am trying to delete duplicates from this list. Specifically, I want to treat lists within `s` which, up to a reordering, contain the same lists (2-tuples) as the same, and keep only one.

For instance, if `s` were my actual list, I would want to convert it into the following list:  `{ {{3,4},{11,5}} , {{5,5},{3,2}} }`.

I can't figure out an efficient way of doing this; in reality, my list `s` is quite large, and its sublists also consist of many elements.

Comment: `DeleteDuplicatesBy[s, Sort]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ s]
```

> ```
> {{{3, 4}, {11, 5}}, {{3, 2}, {5, 5}}}
> ```

You can also use [`Gather`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Gather.html) or [`GatherBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html):

```
Gather[Sort /@ s][[All, 1]]
```

> ```
> {{{3, 4}, {11, 5}}, {{3, 2}, {5, 5}}}
> ```

```
GatherBy[s, Sort][[All, 1]]
```

> ```
> {{{3, 4}, {11, 5}}, {{5, 5}, {3, 2}}}
> ```

All three above are faster than `DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]` for long lists of lists:

```
SeedRandom[1]
ss = RandomInteger[10, {100000, 2, 2}];

r1 = DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ ss]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.038
> ```

```
r2 = Gather[Sort /@ ss][[All, 1]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.12
> ```

```
r3 = GatherBy[ss, Sort][[All, 1]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.13
> ```

```
r4 = DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]@ss; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.15
> ```

```
Sort /@ r1 == Sort /@ r2 == Sort /@ r3 == Sort /@ r4
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
SeedRandom[1]
ss = RandomInteger[10, {100000, 50, 5}];

r1 = DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ ss]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 1.26
> ```

```
r2 = Gather[Sort /@ ss][[All, 1]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 1.69
> ```

```
r3 = GatherBy[ss, Sort][[All, 1]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 1.61
> ```

```
r4 = DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]@ss; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 3.27
> ```

```
Sort /@ r1 == Sort /@ r2 == Sort /@ r3 == Sort /@ r4
```

> ```
> True
> ```